# jquery - get an html attribute from within a function call

Tags: jquery, parameters, qtip

I'm trying to call a different tooltip according to an anchor tag's id attribute. My JavaScript code is as follows:

```
$(function()
{
   $('.tippy').qtip(
   {
      content: {
          url: "http://mydomain.com/product/mini/" + $(this).attr("id") // doesn't work
      },

      hide: { when: 'mouseout', fixed: true },

       position: {
         corner: {
            target: 'bottomRight',
            tooltip: 'topLeft'
         }
      }
   });

});
```

my html code looks like this:

```
<div>this is the text and I would like to reference the <a href="product.php" class="tippy" id="123456">superproduct</a> with qtip.</div>
```

I'm pretty stuck, could you give me a hand please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('.tippy').each(function() {  
   $(this).qtip({
          content: {
              url: "http://mydomain.com/product/mini/" + $(this).attr("id")
          },
          hide: { when: 'mouseout', fixed: true },   
          position: {
             corner: {
                target: 'bottomRight',
                tooltip: 'topLeft'
             }
          }
   });
)};
```

---

The reason why `$(this)` does not work in your code is simple: It is **not** inside a function call (at least not where `this` should refer to a `.tippy` element). `$(this).attr()` is executed when you construct the object that is passed to `qtip()`. That means it is in the same context as `$('.tippy')` and therefore `this` most probably refers to `window`.